# Verizon Jetpac (Mifi 7730L) Connection to Hub or Router?

Tags: networking, router, internet, connection

I currently have a Verizon mobile Jetpack hotspot (MiFi 7730L) and was wondering how to connect it to a router (I can purchase a router) or a hub. The idea is to use MiFi as the source of internet and provide a connection via wireless and hardwire connection to several devices.

The problem is that I want to give internet access to a DVR security recorder that does NOT have an internal or an external Wi-Fi transceiver it only has an Ethernet port.  I have several devices that are wireless and for them, the MiFi works fine.  The security DVR is an ANNKE with a network interface that is RJ45x1(10/100M)

This problem wouldn't exist if the MiFi 7730L had an ethernet port, but it doesn't. It does have a MiFi Charging Port (QuickCharge) — Use to connect the QuickCharge charger, Internet over USB-C, and MiFi Share file sharing via mass storage etc,

Comment: You'll need a router that can act as a wireless bridge. A wireless bridge can connect to a wireless network (the one broadcast by your MiFi) and then either rebroadcast that as another wireless network with better coverage, and/or allow connections over an ethernet port. There are dedicated wireless bridge routers, options in many regular wireless routers, and there are 3rd party software products that add this function to "regular" wireless routers which don't support this function be default.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same hotspot Verizon mifi 7730 L. I bought a USB C to rj45 adapter dongle. I'm using a netgear nighthawk ac 2300 model r7000p. I plug the cat 5 cable in the WAN port on the router and the USB C to the mifi 7730 L. I have no problem connecting to the router. router shows I have internet connection. I've connected mulitiple devices WiFi and LAN ports. MacBook Pro,cellphone, tablet,computer and 4K firestick with no lag. connected laptop using ethernet cable. everything works perfect. one thing to mention is jetpack will not show any device connected but the router will be recieving internet.